# How to put p inside a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, jquery-selectors, anchor

I have this HTML:

```
<a href=#>First</a>
<a href=#>Second</a>
<a href=#>Third</a>
```

How can I have:

```
<a href=#><p class="test">First</p></a>
<a href=#><p class="test">Second</p></a>
<a href=#><p class="test">Third</p></a>
```

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
$(function(){
    $("a").text().prepend("<p class="test">"+ $("a").text() +"</p>");
});
```

I'm newbie, Thanks

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong. You're essentially putting a box in a box and there's no need for that. You could optimize your HTML like this: <a href=# class="test">First</a> You should never have an element that contains only one element because if that's the case then you can simply remove the inner element and apply its style/behavior/content to the outer element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) function:

```
$("a").wrapInner("<p class='test'></p>")
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SYNGc/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$("a").text("<p>"+$("a").text()+"</p>");
```